# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, executable-jar

I'm developing a java code in Netbeans 8 that external jars. The project runs as expected when I run it from Netbeans IDE, but executing the jar generated using the Clean and Build function of the IDE(jar gets placed in the dist directory and the dependent jars in the lib directory inside dist), gives the following error during runtime

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
    at com.informatica.powercenter.sdk.mapfwk.util.Logger.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.informatica.powercenter.sdk.mapfwk.util.Logger.getLogger(Unknown Source)
    at com.informatica.powercenter.sdk.mapfwk.util.JMFMessageCatalog.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.informatica.powercenter.sdk.mapfwk.repository.Repository.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at CM.CreateMappingFresh.createRepository(CreateMappingFresh.java:463)
    at CM.Base.init(Base.java:69)
    at CM.Base.execute(Base.java:57)
    at CM.CreateMappingFresh.pc_main(CreateMappingFresh.java:125)
    at CM.GUI2.jButton_GenerateXMLActionPerformed(GUI2.java:972)
    at CM.GUI2.access$2400(GUI2.java:34)
    at CM.GUI2$26.actionPerformed(GUI2.java:598)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 47 more
```

The class mentioned in the second line of the error (Logger.java) is present in a jar at the location com/informatica/powercenter/sdk/mapfwk/util (as mentioned in the error). This jar is included in the Classpath in the manifest.mf as lib/jarname.jar as well(along with the other jars). Please suggest steps to eliminate this error.

Comment: you sure it's in the classpath?  try making your first line in your main() method:  `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));`

Comment: you sure have log4j.jar in your classpath?

Comment: If you are using maven, then try `exclude`ing that library from the parent library (the one containing the logger library) and `include` it manually.

Comment: pretty positive he's not using maven @Hamid or this would most likely be working.  they are also talking about physical dependencies.

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with `com.informatica....`. Your classpath is missing Log4J.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik @ Satya To my knowledge, log4j.jar was actually not being used in the project when i was running the project through netbeans. However, given the error, I downloaded log4j-1.2.17.jar and added it to the lib dir and classpath. Its still giving the same error. 

(log4j.properties is being used, in case the error could be related to that)

Comment: What does your `Logger` class look like? Its `init` method (instance initializers + constructor) clearly tries to load Log4J's `Logger`.

Comment: hey i made a mistake adding the log4j jar, its running without the error now. Thanks!